# Udisk - Error creating mount point no such file or directory

Tags: mount, archlinux, udisks

I'm trying to automatically mount a USB drive on linux. With all default settings it works and the drive is mounted to /run/media/*username*/*drivename*.

I tried to change the default mount point to /media/*drivename* by following the guide linked here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_to_/media_(udisks2)

I added the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2.rules` with the following contents:

```
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
```

I then rebooted my machine. Now every time I try to access the drive, I get the following error:

**Unable to mount *drivename***

*Error creating mount point '/media/drivename': No such file or directory*

If I remove the file I created and reboot again, the drives are mounted to /run/media/*username*/*drivename* like normal, and I can access them fine.

I'm on Arch linux. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into a similar issue, I simply created the `/media` folder and then rebooted and everything worked. Apparently udisks expected `/media` to already exist.

1. Put 99-udisks2.rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
2. run `mkdir /media` (as sudo)
3. run `reboot`
4. Profit!